# clear cache of clients browsers when making changes

Tags: html, caching, browser-cache

When developing a website using HTML/CSS, during the development phase it makes sense to prevent caching as people viewing the website would otherwise see old versions. Ive seen threads on this before using meta tags ie:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />enter code here
```

However this dosent seem to work with HTML5 and similarly I only want to clear clients cache to empty once Ive made an update.

For example if I have an image in index.html and update this image (same filename different content) then clients would see the previous image

Is there a way I can version html pages such that the clients browser would cache version 1 then on reloading If I change the html to version 2 the cache would be emptied and the new website with all changes would be loaded?

Seems this would need to be the case in most web developments otherwise clients would never see changes

Comment: To clarify this, if I load http://www.mysite.co.uk I get the cached version with the old version in index.php. If I load http://www.mysite.co.uk?q=1 I get the updated version as I expect (obviously because its a new url so cache is not stored for it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the possibility to edit the `<link>` file in the index page (or wherever you load in the  file in. After the .css you need to enter a query like ?v=...

So like this:

OLD FILE: `<link href="/css/TestFile.css" rel="stylesheet">`

After editing it to refresh the cache: `<link href="/css/TestFile.css?v=1" rel="stylesheet">` v standing for version, you can use any character.

This resets the cache for everyone visiting the website and make them see the new version instead of the old version

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, this would work with the CSS but what about images embedded in the html with an <img> tag ie resource caching?

Comment: If I am correct you can use the same thing. <img src="image.jpg?v=1">

Comment: It seems as if the whole index.html page is caching though. In reqular browsing it shows <img src="xxx.png" /> but in incognito it shows <img src="xxx.png?v=1"/>

Comment: Can this method automation by script like using JS or JQuery ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your head content -

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Comment: This isn't the case. The index.php page is being cached. In my original post I mention Ive already tried a similar solution?

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I change a lot an specific JS file and I need it to be in its last version in all browsers where is being used.

I do not have a specific version number for this file, so I simply hash the current date and time (hour and minute) and pass it as the version number:

```
<script src="/js/panel/app.js?v={{ substr(md5(date("Y-m-d_Hi")),10,18) }}"></script>
```

I need it to be loaded every minute, but you can decide when it should be reloaded.

Comment: Similar to my comment on the answer below, this method is valid for files linked by the index.php / index.html file but what about the index file itself.

Comment: Add the following in your head content - @andy-West

 `   <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />`